What is the "no-split-project" option in Gradle "Build Init Plugin"?
The Build Init Plugin of Gradle 8.7 has documentation here.
In the example seen in Sample usage section:
gradle init \
  --type java-application \
  --dsl kotlin \
  --test-framework junit-jupiter \
  --package my.project \
  --project-name my-project  \
  --no-split-project  \
  --java-version 17

… we see the --no-split-project option. Unfortunately that option is not documented.
Does anyone know:

What the no-split-project option do exactly?
What is the opposite, when you do not want that option?
What is the default?
Is there any official documentation?


Does this help? https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/73b46a83d30052c8bc5714373184f6ad9e74b3f5/platforms/software/build-init/src/main/java/org/gradle/buildinit/tasks/InitBuild.java#L122

Executing gradle help --task init will show you the options and their description. On Gradle 8.7 it says --no-split-project disables --split-project, where the latter says "Split functionality across multiple subprojects?". Though that doesn't tell you what exactly will happen. I'm guessing it may depend on the type of project you choose. For instance, when I created an application it asked if I wanted a single "app" project or to split it into "app" and "lib" subprojects. But it didn't ask me at all when creating a library instead.

The opposite of no-split-project is split-project per the source code
To see all the options, use the Help feature.
gradle help --task init

Result for Gradle 8.8-rc-1 is:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :help
Detailed task information for init

Path
     :init

Type
     InitBuild (org.gradle.buildinit.tasks.InitBuild)

Options
     --comments     Include clarifying comments in files.

     --no-comments     Disables option --comments.

     --dsl     Set the build script DSL to be used in generated scripts.
               Available values are:
                    groovy
                    kotlin

     --incubating     Allow the generated build to use new features and APIs.

     --no-incubating     Disables option --incubating.

     --insecure-protocol     How to handle insecure URLs used for Maven Repositories.
                             Available values are:
                                  ALLOW
                                  FAIL
                                  UPGRADE
                                  WARN

     --java-version     Provides java version to use in the project.

     --package     Set the package for source files.

     --project-name     Set the project name.

     --split-project     Split functionality across multiple subprojects?

     --no-split-project     Disables option --split-project.

     --test-framework     Set the test framework to be used.
                          Available values are:
                               cpptest
                               junit
                               junit-jupiter
                               kotlintest
                               scalatest
                               spock
                               testng
                               xctest

     --type     Set the type of project to generate.
                Available values are:
                     basic
                     cpp-application
                     cpp-library
                     groovy-application
                     groovy-gradle-plugin
                     groovy-library
                     java-application
                     java-gradle-plugin
                     java-library
                     kotlin-application
                     kotlin-gradle-plugin
                     kotlin-library
                     pom
                     scala-application
                     scala-library
                     swift-application
                     swift-library

     --use-defaults     Use default values for options not configured explicitly

     --no-use-defaults     Disables option --use-defaults.

     --rerun     Causes the task to be re-run even if up-to-date.

Description
     Initializes a new Gradle build.

Group
     Build Setup

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

The Javadoc may provide a bit more information about each option. For example Javadoc for Gradle 8.7.
I combined the Help and Javadoc info into this table.



Option
Opposite
Help / Javadoc
Values




--comments
--no-comments
Include clarifying comments in files.



--dsl

Set the build script DSL to be used in generated scripts.
groovykotlin


--incubating
--no-incubating
Allow the generated build to use new features and APIs.Can the generated build use new and unstable features? When enabled, the generated build will use new patterns, APIs or features that may be unstable between minor releases. Use this if you'd like to try out the latest features of Gradle. By default, init will generate a build that uses stable features and behavior.



--insecure-protocol

How to handle insecure URLs used for Maven Repositories.
ALLOWFAILUPGRADEWARN


--java-version

Provides java version to use in the project.Java version to be used by generated Java projects. When set, Gradle will use the provided value as the target major Java version for all relevant generated projects. Gradle will validate the number to ensure it is a valid and supported major version.



--package

Set the package for source files.



--project-name

Set the project name.The name of the generated project, defaults to the name of the directory the project is generated in. This property can be set via command-line option '--project-name'.



--split-project
--no-split-project
Split functionality across multiple subprojects?The desired DSL of build scripts to create, defaults to 'kotlin'.



--test-framework

Set the test framework to be used.
cpptestjunitjunit-jupiterkotlintestscalatestspocktestngxctest


--type

Set the type of project to generate.Defaults to 'basic' - a minimal scaffolding, following Gradle best practices. If a pom.xml is found in the project root directory, the type defaults to 'pom' and the existing project is converted to Gradle.
basiccpp-applicationcpp-librarygroovy-applicationgroovy-gradle-plugingroovy-library java-applicationjava-gradle-pluginjava-librarykotlin-applicationkotlin-gradle-pluginkotlin-librarypomscala-applicationscala-libraryswift-applicationswift-library


--use-defaults
--no-use-defaults
Use default values for options not configured explicitlyWhen true, the interactive dialog is skipped, and no user input is required to complete the command.



--rerun

Causes the task to be re-run even if up-to-date.




